# Presenting views using associated value of enum case

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm passing an object of a coredata model(`ItemModel`) using enums like this

```
.sheet(item: $activeSheet, onDismiss: { self.activeSheet = nil }) { item in

            switch item {
            case .newDoc:
                NewDocumentView(ref: nil).environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
            case .detailFolder(let data):
                DetailedFolderView(item: data, dirName: data.wrappedName, updater: viewUpdater).environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
            case .detailDoc(let file):
                DetailDocumentView(item: file, fileName: file.wrappedItemName)
                    .environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
            }
        }
```

but while i try to update the `ItemModel` object in the `DetailDocumentView` using the managed object context after saving and dismissing the view the parent view isnt updated, the view updates only after restarting the app

Can anyone suggest a way to update the parent view after updating the object of the coredata model(`ItemModel`) being passed in `DetailDocumentView`. Any suggestions are welcome :)

Been stuck on this issue for hours, tried using observable objects, tried using a publisher when context is updated, but noting has worked so far :(

Heres a reference of the code used when tapped on a file to present `DetailDocumentView`

```
/// creates a grid to display data
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - geometry: setup dimension for the grid view
    ///   - folders: files required
    /// - Returns: returns a grid
    private func gridView(_ geometry: GeometryProxy, files: FetchedResults<ItemModel>) -> some View {
        QGrid(files,
              columns: 2,
              columnsInLandscape: 0,
              vSpacing: 20,
              hSpacing: 35,
              vPadding: 10,
              hPadding: 10,
              isScrollable: false,
              showScrollIndicators: false) { file in
            FileItemView(item: file)
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.activeSheet = .detailDoc(file: file)
                }
        }
    }
```

The enum case I used to present multiple sheet is below

```
/// for presenting sheets
enum HomeViewActiveSheet: Any {
    case newDoc
    case detailFolder(folder: FolderModel)
    case detailDoc(file: ItemModel)
}

// so that it can be used in the .sheet init
extension HomeViewActiveSheet: Identifiable {
    var id: ObjectIdentifier {
        ObjectIdentifier(Self.self)
    }
}
```

And I declare it in the parent class as this:

```
@State private var activeSheet: HomeViewActiveSheet? = .none
```

Comment: Would you show more code? How `file` goes here?

Comment: sure ill added the enum here